# How do you convert a list of numbers into a map?

Tags: clojure

I have a list of keys: `(1 2 3 4)`

I want a map with the values set to 0 like this: `{1 0, 2 0, 3 0, 4 0}`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do something like this with the zipmap function:

```
(zipmap '(1 2 3 4) (repeat 0))
=> {4 0, 3 0, 2 0, 1 0}
```

zipmap takes a list of keys and a list of values and converts them into a map.  The `repeat` function creates an infinite sequence of 0s.  `zipmap` stops when it reaches the end of the shorter list, so just don't pass it two infinite sequences :)

Comment: In my original map function, I had an additional function on the key.  (map (fn[key] (foo key)..)..is there a way to incorporate that function into the zipmap or should I just apply the function before I use zipmap?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as map returns a sequence. Just replace '(1 2 3 4) with your map function: e.g. if you wanted to convert the numbers to a string before making them the key:
    (zipmap (map #(str %) '(1 2 3 4)) (repeat 0))
    => {"4" 0, "3" 0, "2" 0, "1" 0}

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a function with James' zipmap:

```
Clojure=> (defn map-to-n [n] (zipmap (range 1 n) (repeat 0)))
#'user/map-to-n
Clojure=> (map-to-n 10)
{9 0, 8 0, 7 0, 6 0, 5 0, 4 0, 3 0, 2 0, 1 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

The more general pattern for this is to use `(apply collection list` to create the collection. The Clojure collections all have "constructors" or creation functions that take a variable number of arguments and return thows arguments bundled up in the collection. if your arguments are already wrapped up in another collection then apply is a convenient way to take them out of the collection and pass them to the creation function as arguments.

This is a lot more work. which is why we have wrapper functions like zipmap.

Answer (score 1):

Wow I didn't know about zipmap, thats useful

I would have done it like this

```
(apply hash-map (interleave '(1 2 3 4)  (repeat 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way, which retains the original order of the keys (up to 9 keys!):

`(defn list-to-map [& n]
  (->> (map vector n (repeat 0))
       (into (hash-map))))`

`(list-to-map 1 2 3 4)` => `{1 0, 2 0, 3 0, 4 0}`

`(list-to-map 4 3 2 1)` => `{4 0, 3 0, 2 0, 1 0}`

Comment: Watch out: Hash maps don't have a defined order so you should never rely on that. The ordering you're seeing is coincidental due to the implementation of hash maps. See what happens when you try that with 9 items.

Comment: Yes you are right. It retains the order till the 9. item, so it has the same order till up to 9 arguments! Do you know the reason?

Comment: Use the `type` function to see the resulting type at 8 entries and 9. I believe Clojure uses an "array map" for smaller maps as a performance optimisation. Using small maps to pass bits of data around is a common use case where there's no need to use the clever machinery of the full persistent hash map.